# PostgreSQL: ANY (VALUES(...)) in WHERE clause causes drastic slowdown

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, query-performance

Okay, I [previously](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136423/postgresql-slow-join-on-three-large-tables) asked a question regarding a large dataset but it was never answered, so I decided to cut it down and ask about a smaller subset of the previous setup and simplify what I am trying to accomplish in a new question - hoping this will be a bit clearer.

I have a single large table (`report_drugs`) that is 1775 MB on disk containing little over 33 million rows. The table layout:

```sql
    Column     |            Type             | Modifiers 
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 rid           | integer                     | not null
 drug          | integer                     | not null
 created       | timestamp without time zone | 
 reason        | text                        | 
 duration      | integer                     | 
 drugseq       | integer                     | 
 effectiveness | integer                     | 
Indexes:
  "report_drugs_drug_idx" btree (drug) CLUSTER
  "report_drugs_drug_rid_idx" btree (drug, rid)
  "report_drugs_reason_idx" btree (reason)
  "report_drugs_reason_rid_idx" btree (reason, rid)
  "report_drugs_rid_idx" btree (rid)
```

As you can see, I have several indexes (not all relevant to this question) and have `CLUSTER`ed the table on the `drug` column index as this is mostly used to scope on. The table is also `VACUUM ANALYZE`d automatically and manually by me before getting any metrics.

Yet a simple query like this:

```sql
SELECT drug, reason FROM report_drugs WHERE drug = ANY(VALUES  (9557), (17848),
(17880), (18223), (18550), (19020), (19084), (19234), (21295), (21742), 
(23085), (26017), (27016), (29317), (33566), (35818), (37394), (39971), 
(41505), (42162), (44000), (45168), (47386), (48848), (51472), (51570), 
(51802), (52489), (52848), (53663), (54591), (55506), (55922), (57209), 
(57671), (59311), (62022), (62532), (63485), (64134), (66236), (67394), 
(67586), (68134), (68934), (70035), (70589), (70896), (73466), (75931), 
(78686), (78985), (79217), (83294), (83619), (84964), (85831), (88330), 
(89998), (90440), (91171), (91698), (91886), (91887), (93219), (93766), 
(94009), (96341), (101475), (104623), (104973), (105216), (105496), 
(106428), (110412), (119567), (121154));
```

Will take well over 7 seconds to complete and has the follow query plan:

```sql
Nested Loop  (cost=1.72..83532.00 rows=24164 width=26) (actual time=0.947..7385.490 rows=264610 loops=1)
->  HashAggregate  (cost=1.16..1.93 rows=77 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.036 rows=77 loops=1)
     Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1
     ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.96 rows=77 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.007 rows=77 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using report_drugs_drug_idx on report_drugs  (cost=0.56..1081.67 rows=314 width=26) (actual time=0.239..95.568 rows=3436 loops=77)
     Index Cond: (drug = "*VALUES*".column1)
Planning time: 7.009 ms
Execution time: 7393.408 ms
```

The more values I add to my `ANY(VALUES(..))` clause, the slower it gets. This query can sometimes contain over 200 values, which will then take well over 30 seconds to complete. Yet including only a few values (4 ex.) gives me a query in under 200 ms. Thus it is clearly this part of the `WHERE` clause that is causing this slowdown.

What might I do to make this query perform better? 
What obvious points am I missing here?

**My hardware and database settings:**

I'm running the cluster from an SSD drive. The system has a total memory of 24 GB, runs on Debian and uses an 4Ghz 8 core i7-4790 processor. It should be sufficient hardware for this kind of dataset.

Some important `postgresql.conf` readouts:

- shared_buffers = 4GB
- work_mem = 100MB
- checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
- autovacuum = on

**A side question to this:**

Previously I had used `WHERE drug = ANY(ARRAY[..])`, but I found that using `WHERE drug = ANY(VALUES(..))` gives me a significant speed boost. Why should that make a difference?

---

**Edit 1 - JOIN on VALUES instead of WHERE clause**

As *a_horse_with_no_name* pointed out in the comments, I tried to remove the `WHERE` clause and perform the query using a `JOIN` on the drug values:

Query:

```sql
SELECT drug, reason FROM report_drugs d JOIN (VALUES  (9557), (17848),
(17880), (18223), (18550), (19020), (19084), (19234), (21295), (21742), 
(23085), (26017), (27016), (29317), (33566), (35818), (37394), (39971), 
(41505), (42162), (44000), (45168), (47386), (48848), (51472), (51570), 
(51802), (52489), (52848), (53663), (54591), (55506), (55922), (57209), 
(57671), (59311), (62022), (62532), (63485), (64134), (66236), (67394), 
(67586), (68134), (68934), (70035), (70589), (70896), (73466), (75931), 
(78686), (78985), (79217), (83294), (83619), (84964), (85831), (88330), 
(89998), (90440), (91171), (91698), (91886), (91887), (93219), (93766), 
(94009), (96341), (101475), (104623), (104973), (105216), (105496), 
(106428), (110412), (119567), (121154)) as x(d) on x.d = d.drug;
```

Plan (with `analyze` and `buffers` as requested by *jjanes*):

```sql
Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..83531.04 rows=24164 width=26) (actual time=1.003..6927.080 rows=264610 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=12514 read=111251
  ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.96 rows=77 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.059 rows=77 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using report_drugs_drug_idx on report_drugs d  (cost=0.56..1081.67 rows=314 width=26) (actual time=0.217..89.551 rows=3436 loops=77)
        Index Cond: (drug = "*VALUES*".column1)
        Buffers: shared hit=12514 read=111251
Planning time: 7.616 ms
Execution time: 6936.466 ms
```

However, this seems to have no effect. While the query plan changed a bit, the execution time is roughly the same and the query is still slow.

---

**Edit 2 - JOIN on temporary table instead of JOIN on VALUES**

Following *Lennart*'s advise I tried to create a temporary table within a single transaction, filling it with the drug values and joining against that. Although I gain ~2 seconds, the query is still very slow at little over 5 seconds.

The query plan has changed from a `nested loop` to a `hash join` and it is now doing a `sequential scan` on the `report_drugs` table. Could this be a missing index somehow (the `drug` column in the `report_drugs` table does have an index...)?

```sql
Hash Join  (cost=67.38..693627.71 rows=800224 width=26) (actual time=0.711..4999.222 rows=264610 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (d.drug = t.drug)
  ->  Seq Scan on report_drugs d  (cost=0.00..560537.16 rows=33338916 width=26) (actual time=0.410..3144.117 rows=33338915 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=35.50..35.50 rows=2550 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=77 loops=1)
      Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 35kB
      ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=77 loops=1)
Planning time: 7.030 ms
Execution time: 5005.621 ms
```

Comment: Try joining against a values clause: `FROM drugs join ( VALUES  (9557), ... ) as x(d) on x.d = drugs.drug`

Comment: Can you turn track_io_timing on and run `explain (analyze, buffers)`?

Comment: If you run the same query repeatedly with the same values list, does it get faster?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I added a `JOIN` and updated my question with the new query plan, however this query is equally as slow.

Comment: @jjanes The new query plan I added is with `buffers` enabled. Also, the query does not get faster when run multiple times (well it does due to PostgreSQL/OS caching, but this cache is cleared on every test I do to get realistic timing results)

Comment: A query without caching is not "realistic". Or do you disable all caching in production and run your server with 128MB RAM?

Comment: Well, by 'realistic' I mean that the parameters to the query change constantly, thus running the query from cache does not give me honest results *when tuning the performance of the query*. Of course it is fast the second time, the exact buffers are already cached in memory. Though in real use the values used for drugs will never be the same.

Comment: Your data is 1.8GB while your shared_buffers are 4GB, and your RAM is substantially greater yet.  All of your data fits in memory.  All the data needed to satisfy all permutations of this query should fit in the cache simultaneously.  That the parameters keep changing doesn't matter.  If you think it does matter, the correct way to test it is to keep issuing the same query but with different parameters; rather than constantly restarting your server.

Comment: @jjanes I think you have a point indeed. Yet this table is not the only table in the entire database (and certainly not the biggest table) which is constantly being queried. However ... if you think the only way to get performance out of this table is by caching, does this mean that there is no more efficient way to rewrite this query? The bottleneck here is thus pure I/O?

Comment: "The more values I add to my ANY(VALUES(..)) clause, the slower it gets" - we can get up to 2500 there and it's ridiculous how slow it is. Nothing helped us, so far

Answer (score 3):

You're just comparing against a list of values, using IN would be simpler in this case:

```
SELECT drug, reason FROM drugs WHERE drug IN (9557,17848,17880,18223,18550);
```

Alternatively, if you still use ANY, using an array literal results in the same query plan as IN for me:

```
SELECT drug, reason FROM drugs WHERE drug = ANY ('{9557,17848,17880,18223,18550}');
```

I tried this is a smaller test table, and Postgres was able to do an index scan for the version of the query using IN and ANY with an array literal, but not for the query using ANY with VALUES.

The resulting plan is something like the following (but my test table and data is somewhat different):

```
Index Scan using test_data_id_idx on test_data  (cost=0.43..57.43 rows=12 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.028 rows=12 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}'::integer[]))
```

This should be much faster than the query plan you showed as it scans the index once, while your plan loops as many times as you have drugs in that WHERE clause.

Comment: Comparing to a list of values using `IN` would get translated by the planner into an `ANY(ARRAY[..])` clause as this is more efficient. As I pointed on in my question I switched from using `ANY(ARRAY[..])` to using `ANY(VALUES(..))` as this is significantly faster.

Comment: @Timusan Your VALUES statement does seem to confuse the optimizer, I get completely different plans when using your VALUES query compared to using an array literal or IN.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried re-writing using a join? Something like:

```
SELECT d.drug, d.reason 
FROM drugs d
JOIN (VALUES  (9557), (17848), (17880), (18223), (18550), (19020)
            , (19084), (19234), (21295), (21742), (23085), (26017)
            , ... ) as T(drug)
    ON d.drug = T.drug;
```

As a side note, some of your indexes appears to be redundant.

Edit: use temp table

You may also want to try to use a temp table instead of a virtual table. In a transaction do:

```
CREATE TABLE T (drug int not null primary key) ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO T(drug)
VALUES (9557), (17848), (17880), (18223), (18550), ...;

SELECT d.drug, d.reason 
FROM drugs d
JOIN T
    ON d.drug = T.drug;
```

Comment: This was pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name as well, I have updated my question with the result. Unfortunately, this has next to no effect on timing.

Comment: I've added an example of using a temp table instead of joining against a values clause. The idea is that the index created by the primary key may help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it and updated my question with the results. I gain ~2 seconds, but the query is still very slow and I get sequential scans now (no index usage on either table).